# Android ImageFormat.YUV_420_888 in FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

Im using ffmpeg on Android. I have an image with the format `ImageFormat.YUV_420_888`and want to put the image into an `AVFrame`. The Problem is that I dont know what format `ImageFormat.YUV_420_888` is in ffmpeg. I tried with `AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P` but the result looks like this:
[Wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvXWi.png)

It shoud look so:
[Right result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY1hl.png)

Here is how I copy the data:

```
Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
for(int i = 0; i < planes.length; i++)
{
    BytePointer plane = new BytePointer(planes[i].getBuffer());
    tmpAVFrame.data(i, plane);
}
```

**Edit**:
With Pixel format `AV_PIX_FMT_YUV440P` only the colors are wrong:
[Wrong Colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0h8Ih.png)